# Not able to collect coverage in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using JEST to unit test my app. The test execution is running fine. However I am not able to collect code coverage correctly. The coverage is only logged for folder where I have the jest config file. Snapshot of folder structure:

[image]

In the console the coverage is only generated for enzyme-config.js. I tried using `"collectCoverageFrom" : ["**/src/**/*.js"]` but it throws me Unknown for all params. Am I missing something here?

jest-setup.json:

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./enzyme.setup.js",
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-teamcity-reporter",
    "coverageReporters": [
        "teamcity", "lcov", "text"
   ],
   "collectCoverageFrom" : ["**/src/**/*.js"],
    "roots": [
      "../../../__tests__/unit"
    ]
}
```

Coverage log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A double star notation (**) like you are using in your `collectCoverageFrom` array, will only match file and folders which are in or in subfolders of the current folder. Assuming jest will match these files based on the folder in which the setup is defined, it will not find any files outside of the subtree which it is in. You might want to try `../src/**/*.js`.